# Send email on SELinux violation

Tags: fedora, email, selinux

On my desktop I get a GNOME notification when an SELinux violation has occurred which makes debugging simple but for servers I do not have this. Is there any way I can set up SELinux so when there is a violation it sends me an email with the details?

**NOTE:** I have a couple (2) servers that I'd want to deploy this on

Comment: Yes, setroubleshoot can send email as described in [this FAQ](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Docs/Drafts/SELinux/SETroubleShoot/UserFAQ#2.3._Can_setroubleshoot_send_me_an_email_when_an_alert_fires.3F).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on one of the [comments regarding `setroubleshoot`](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Docs/Drafts/SELinux/SETroubleShoot/UserFAQ#2.3._Can_setroubleshoot_send_me_an_email_when_an_alert_fires.3F) you can install this extra package like so:

```
$ sudo yum install -y setroubleshoot
```

Once installed take a look at its config file, specifically this section:

```
[email]
# recipients_filepath: Path name of file with email recipients. One address
# per line, optionally followed by enable flag. Comment character is #.
recipients_filepath = /var/lib/setroubleshoot/email_alert_recipients
```

Now go ahead and create that file referenced:

```
$ echo "myemail@mydom.com" > /var/lib/setroubleshoot/email_alert_recipients
```

Then restart/start the service:

```
$ sudo systemctl start setroubleshoot
```

#### Advanced options

`setroubleshoot` also provides the ability to filter the SE alerts through the email_alert_recipients file:

```
jdennis@redhat.com                       filter_type=after_first
```

These filters are a bit hard to [gleam from the docs](https://docs.pagure.org/setroubleshoot/SETroubleShootUserFAQ.html#email-alerts) but they go as follows:

> - `Ignore After First` Alert::
>
>   - This is the default. The address will receive an alert only the first time it fires. Email alerts will be filtered for the alert in
>       question for all subsequent firings of the alert.
> - `Never Ignore`::
>
>   - An email alert will be sent for every instance of every alert to this address.
> - `Ignore Always`::
>
>   - Email alerts will never be sent for this address. One can use this to temporarily disable alerts to an address.
>
>     But I don't have a desktop session on the node I want to receive
>       email alerts for? For instance how can I monitor a server?
>
>     You can directly edit the file
>       `/var/lib/setroubleshoot/email_alert_recipients`. This is the file the
>       above GUI is modifying. The format of the file is line based, the hash
>       (#) character is the comment character, the comment extends to the end
>       of the line, blank lines are ignored.
> - **NOTE:** Addresses are one per line, optionally following the address
>     (separated by whitespace) are options in the form name=value.
>     Currently there is only one option:
>
>   - `filter_type`::
>       `after_first`, `never`, or `always`
>
> *I heavily edited the above snippet, but tried to keep the "spirit" of this section from the FAQ.*

#### References

- [Linux OS Service ‘setroubleshoot’](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/linux-os-service-setroubleshoot/)

Answer (score 0):

For a couple of servers, a better way of having alerts is using the `logcheck` package.

You install `logcheck` in the server side, and define rules to process and send you email over the intended rules that you want to trigger emails.

In that way, if tomorrow you need other rules that are not SELinux, you can add them.

`logcheck` already comes with a default set of rules. I used `logcheck` for a while when I had a smaller infra-structure of a couple of Linux servers in the past.

Obviously for sending email, you also have to have an MTA server side with a minimum of configuration for being able to send you email. Depending whether the email is internal or for gmail, you will have to setup it up differently.

For a bigger infra-structure I would advise having a central syslog server, and handling the logs on that server, however from your answer of 2 servers I wont further elaborate this point.